# I messed with my laptops EFI Boot Manager, now I can’t boot into anything

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, bios

I have an Acer Predator G9-791. I erased Windows 10 in order to install ElementaryOS. I was having issues with EOS booting, so I followed some guides that showed how to use boot-repair, edit the efibootmgr, and remove the Raid0 configuration.

After doing this, I am no longer able to boot into anything. I have a USB with Windows 10 on it for recovery purposes, but the laptop BIOS doesn’t recognize that a USB is plugged in. It’s a known good drive.

Is my laptop bricked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The laptop is **not** bricked, since you can access BIOS.
- If the USB drive is not FAT32, likely the UEFI/BIOS cannot read it.
- A quick test would be to [make a bootable USB for *Ubuntu Live*](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) using *Rufus*.

  - Download the *Ubuntu* ISO, e.g., [22.04 LTS](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), which should have all drivers for a 2016 laptop.
  - Download [*Rufus*](https://rufus.ie/en/), which is used to make the bootable USB from the ISO image.
  - Start *Rufus*, point it to the downloaded ISO, and make the boot media.
  - In BIOS, set the machine to *allow* booting from USB. Shut down.
  - *Hold down* the appropriate key (e.g., <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, etc.) to change boot order, push the power button, and boot from the USB.
  - If the PC runs Ubuntu right from USB, you know it is working.
  - At any time, you can choose to [actually install *Ubuntu*](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish/) on the HDD, which should take less than half an hour. Since there is no working OS or data on the HDD, you can choose "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" – It will erase the entire disk and will create the partitions *automatically*.

Yes, this is not [*elementary OS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS), based on *Ubuntu*, but the standard *Ubuntu* installer is well-tested and should make life easier. Once you get that working, you can try installing *elementary OS*

Comment: Followed your instructions. I was able to boot into the Ubuntu live cd and even install Ubuntu. However, my computer simply boot loops when I reboot it after install. 

I’ve attempted to fix the ‘efibootmgr’ by running boot-repair and adding an entry for Ubuntu that points to the specified file. This has not helped. 

When I boot back into the live cd and check efibootmgr, the changes I made are gone.

Comment: If you wish to make a *persistent* boot USB device, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330368/live-usb-with-persistence-vs-full-install-on-usb . However, I do not recommend that, because most flash USB devices are *slow*, causing all operations to run *slowly* (though it might work better on an external SSD). To remedy the boot loop, you might completely remove **all** partitions from your main drive, leaving *all* as unassigned, then create a single partition and then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I do not want to create a persistent boot device. I would love to get my computer to boot into something though. 

As it stands, my computer absolutely refuses to boot into whatever I install. I installed EOS and was unable to boot in. It shows up as “Command Linpus Lite” with the M.2 drive’s ID in parentheses. 

I then installed Ubuntu and had the same issue. 

I’ve formatted these drives several times at this point. I’ve made sure they were ext4 for my /root drive and FAT32 for the UEFI files. 

I’ve made sure to create them as GPT partition tables. I’m at a total loss.